# Powershell - How can I locate where Aliases and Functions are defined?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, path, alias

#### Background

At some point in time, I know I created a file that defines some functions and assigns aliases to them. These are available in all powershell instances.

The problem is, I can't for my life remember where this file is now that I want to add some more.

#### What I've Tried

I've tried `Get-Command` with no helpful output, and I've also checked my `PATH` for folders, but none that contain this script are present :/

`Get-Command` output:
[Output of Get-Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTEbx.png)

User `PATH`:
[User PATH locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA85V.png)

System `PATH`
[System PATH locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Ha0.png)

#### What to do?

How can I locate where these Aliases and Functions are defined?

Comment: if they are available everywhere, aren't they stored in the `$profile` ?

Comment: I would recursively `grep` a certain folder for a specific character string that you still remember to have created at a certain point in time. `grep` in PowerShell is `Select-String`.

Comment: as SimonS pointed out, the usual place for that is in one of the files listed via `$profile | Select-Object -Property *`. the one you likely want is is the `AllUsersAllHosts` one - that applies to every PoSh instance. you may have used the `CurrentUserAllHosts` one, tho. ///// you can test all that by starting PoSh with the `-NoProfile` command line option.

Comment: @SimonS - Thanks a bunch! I had totally forgotten that it's called a "profile" in windows xP Thanks to the command by Lee_dailey I found the files and found the one defining the Functions. Could you please add it as an answer so that I can close this question?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thanks for the command! I found the right folder and could finally adit some old functions and add some new ones :) Maybe post as an answer instead of comment?

Comment: @MihaiDobrescu, this sounds useful in other contexts too. Is there a way to recursively execute Select-String on every file and folder in Windows?

Comment: @ErikW.Development I would highly suggest to use notepad++ and their "Search in File" Option instead of PowerShell if you want to search for certain patterns in files. it's faster and super reliable.

Comment: @ErikW.Development - done! please, let me know if you see anything that needs improvement ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Erik W. Development, try this PowerShell one-liner: `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern 'SoughtForData' -CaseSensitive`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the usual source of "always there" code is one [or more] of the profile files. you can find them thus ...

```
$profile | Select-Object -Property *
```

since you are seeing this in all hosts, the one you likely need to check is the `AllUsersAllHosts` OR the `CurrentUserAllHosts` versions.

the profile files don't exist by default, so you may find nothing there for any given one. also, the list of files varies for ps5.1 versus ps7 AND for every host [ISE/powershell.exe/pwsh.exe/VSCode_PoSh_addon/etc.] ... so you will need to check for the versions that are specific to each - and do it from inside each host.

my ps5.1 listing from inside the ISE ...

```
AllUsersAllHosts       : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
AllUsersCurrentHost    : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
CurrentUserAllHosts    : D:\Data\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
CurrentUserCurrentHost : D:\Data\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
Length                 : 71
```

note that i have redirected my `MyDocuments` dir. [*grin*]

for ps7, the list is as follows ...

```
AllUsersAllHosts       : C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\profile.ps1
AllUsersCurrentHost    : C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
CurrentUserAllHosts    : D:\Data\Documents\PowerShell\profile.ps1
CurrentUserCurrentHost : D:\Data\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
Length                 : 61
```

note the different locations in the 1st two profile listings.

Comment: Hey Lee, how do I know if a Variable has more properties than just what they print out? Like how do I know `$Profile` has 5 Properties?

Comment: there are at least 3 ways. [*grin*] ///// [1] use `Get-Member` [2] use `Select-Object -Property *` [3] use `$Var.PSObject.Properties` [the `.PSObject` property is hidden, so you will have to type in the whole prop name.]

Comment: I don't mean how do i do it, i mean how do i know that i should even try it :P

Comment: @SimonS - you just need to look when you think there may be something interesting there ...or when you think there _should_ be something worth looking for. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

What Lee_Dailey stated in his last comment to you.

Yet, here are a few other approaches that can be used for discovery. Well, set up for defaults and then compare to session created stuff, then get details from either. This can also be used for session cleanups.

```
# Collect all automatic environment resources
$AutomaticVariables    = Get-Variable
$AutomaticVModules     = Get-Module
$AutomaticAliases      = Get-Alias
$AutomaticApplications = Get-Command -CommandType Application
$AutomaticCmdlets      = Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet
$AutomaticFunctions    = Get-Command -CommandType Function
```

Point of note doing this does take a bit of time to collect them all, so it will slow down your $profile load times.

Yet, you can then look this info up as needed, for example:

```
# Get details about a selection
$AutomaticAliases.SyncRoot | 
Out-GridView -PassThru | 
Select-Object -Property '*' | 
Format-List -Force

After making a selection from the grid, in this case an alias from the Pester module:

# Results
<#
HelpUri             : https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/the-truth-about-bdd
ResolvedCommandName : GherkinStep
DisplayName         : Given -> GherkinStep
ReferencedCommand   : GherkinStep
ResolvedCommand     : GherkinStep
Definition          : GherkinStep
Options             : None
Description         : 
OutputType          : {}
Name                : Given
CommandType         : Alias
Source              : Pester
Version             : 4.10.1
Visibility          : Public
ModuleName          : Pester
Module              : Pester
RemotingCapability  : PowerShell
Parameters          : {[Name, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [Test, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [Verbose, 
                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [Debug, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [ErrorAction, 
                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [WarningAction, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [InformationAction, 
                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [ErrorVariable, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [WarningVariable, 
                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [InformationVariable, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [OutVariable, 
                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [OutBuffer, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [PipelineVariable, 
                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata]}
ParameterSets       : 
#>
```

or using Get-Member from a selection

```
$AutomaticAliases.SyncRoot | 
Out-GridView -PassThru | 
Select-Object -Property '*' | 
Get-Member | 
Format-List -Force
```

Or this...

```
($AutomaticAliases.SyncRoot | 
Out-GridView -PassThru | 
Select-Object -Property '*').PSObject.Properties
```

Say, once you know what module (or whatever) the alias is in, then do something like this :

```
Get-Module -Name $($AutomaticAliases.SyncRoot | 
Out-GridView -PassThru).Source | 
Select-Object -Property Name, Path
# Results
<#
Name   Path                                                                         
----   ----                                                                         
Pester C:\Users\postanote\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\4.10.1\Pester.psm1
#>
```

Lastly, as noted, get only the ones you created in the current session and then dig at those details in a similar fashion.

```
# Get only variables created/used during the session
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Variable) -DifferenceObject $AutomaticVariables -Property Name -PassThru |
Where -Property Name -ne 'AutomaticVariables' | 
Out-GridView -Title 'variables created/used during the session' -PassThru

# Get only modules loaded during the session
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Module) -DifferenceObject $AutomaticVModules -Property Name -PassThru |
Where -Property Name -ne 'AutomaticVModules' | 
Out-GridView -Title 'modules created/used during the session' -PassThru

# Get only aliases loaded during the session
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Alias) -DifferenceObject $AutomaticAliases -Property Name -PassThru |
Where -Property Name -ne 'AutomaticAliases' | 
Out-GridView -Title 'variables created/used during the session' -PassThru

# Get only applicatrions loaded during the session
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Command -CommandType Function) -DifferenceObject $AutomaticApplications  -Property Name -PassThru |
Where -Property Name -ne 'AutomaticApplications' | 
Out-GridView -Title 'variables created/used during the session' -PassThru

# Get only cmdlets loaded during the session
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Command -CommandType Function) -DifferenceObject $AutomaticCmdlets  -Property Name -PassThru |
Where -Property Name -ne 'AutomaticCmdlets' | 
Out-GridView -Title 'variables created/used during the session' -PassThru

# Get only functions loaded during the session
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Command -CommandType Function) -DifferenceObject $AutomaticFunctions  -Property Name -PassThru |
Where -Property Name -ne 'AutomaticFunctions' | 
Out-GridView -Title 'variables created/used during the session' -PassThru
```

One can also just use the PSDrives to get this if you don't want to do all the aforementioned. For example:

```
Get-PSDrive | Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#

Name     Used (GB) Free (GB) Provider    Root                CurrentLocation
----     --------- --------- --------    ----                ---------------
Alias                        Alias                                          
C           182.46    293.27 FileSystem  C:\                WINDOWS\system32
Cert                         Certificate \                                  
...                               
Env                          Environment                                    
...                              
Function                     Function                                       
HKCU                         Registry    HKEY_CURRENT_USER                  
HKLM                         Registry    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE                 
...                              
Variable                     Variable                                       
...                                      
#>

Get-ChildItem -Path 'Alias:\' | 
Select-Object -Property Name, Source, PSPRovider, PSPath | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Name               Source                          PSProvider                      PSPath                                             
----               ------                          ----------                      ------                                             
%                                                  Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias::%                 
?                                                  Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias::?                 
__                 PSKoans                         Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias::__                
____               PSKoans                         Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias::____              
ac                                                 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias::ac                
Add-ShouldOperator Pester                          Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias::Add-ShouldOperator
alco               ModuleLibrary                   Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Alias::alco   
...
#>

Get-ChildItem -Path 'Function:\'  | 
Select-Object -Property Name, Source, PSPRovider, PSPath | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
<#
Name                                   Source                       PSProvider                         PSPath                                                      
----                                   ------                       ----------                         ------                                                      
A:                                                                  Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function::A:                      
Add-AssertionOperator                  Pester                       Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function::Add-AssertionOperator   
Add-MenuItem                           PSharp                       Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function::Add-MenuItem            
Add-SubMenuItem                        PSharp                       Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function::Add-SubMenuItem         
AfterAll                               Pester                       Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function::AfterAll                
AfterEach                              Pester                       Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function::AfterEach               
AfterEachFeature                       Pester                       Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function::AfterEachFeature        
AfterEachScenario                      Pester                       Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function::AfterEachScenario 
Assert-FolderExists                    ModuleLibrary                Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Function::Assert-FolderExists 
...
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the defining file of a **function** is trivial using `FunctionInfo.ScriptBlock`. Here's how I would find my `md` function's definition:

```
(v) ➜ ~ Get-Command md

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        md

(v) ➜ ~ (Get-Command md).ScriptBlock.File
/Users/walshca/OneDrive/bin/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
(v) ➜ ~
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to find the file that defined an alias from an `AliasInfo`. I'm pretty sure it's not possible unless you text-search the files your profile loads.

Comment: This is not PSv7 specific. You've been able to do this in Windows PowerShell for years now the same way.